# How to enable a datagrid column text in C#/ wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an app in which as soon as I click the "Insert" I want the program to enable the text in data grid and the user can enter the information of the product. Can someone help me with how can I do this?

below the app code and picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvUyf.png)

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Produtos</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Unidades</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Empresas</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Operadores</TextBlock>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaProdutos}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding ProdutoSelecionado}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descrição" Binding="{Binding Descricao, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaUnidades}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding UnidadeSelecionada}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descrição" Binding="{Binding Descricao, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaEmpresas}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding EmpresaSelecionada}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descrição" Binding="{Binding Descricao, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding ListaOperadores}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding OperadorSelecionado}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nome" Binding="{Binding Nome, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Command="{Binding InserirProdutoCommand}" Width="50" Height="25">Inserir</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding ExcluirProdutoCommand}" Width="50" Height="25">Excluir</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Command="{Binding InserirUnidadeCommand}" Width="50" Height="25">Inserir</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding ExcluirUnidadeCommand}" Width="50" Height="25">Excluir</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Command="{Binding InserirEmpresaCommand}" Width="50" Height="25">Inserir</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding ExcluirEmpresaCommand}" Width="50" Height="25">Excluir</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Command="{Binding InserirOperadorCommand}" Width="50" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Inserir</Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding ExcluirOperadorCommand}" Width="50" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center">Excluir</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <Border Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" BorderThickness="0 1 0 0" BorderBrush="Gray" Margin="10,10,5,0" Padding="5 5 5 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="46">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button Command="{Binding SalvarCommand}" Width="80" Height="30">Salvar</Button>
                <Button Command="{Binding CancelarCommand}" Width="80" Height="30">Cancelar</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: why you need to imply this demand?  You can double-click on the text in DataGridTextColumn ,and modify the text.

Comment: because the user asked for it being easier to enter the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to meet the require,but it needs object bound to Datagrid has a boolean property.Here's the xaml:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="120">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox
                                Name="innerTextBox"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                IsReadOnly="{Binding DisableEdit, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and here is the object:
 public class Person:BindableBase
    {
        private string name;

```
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private bool disableEdit;

    public bool DisableEdit
    {
        get { return disableEdit; }
        set { SetProperty(ref disableEdit, value); }
    }

}
```

And here is button_click event:

```
        var person = datagrid.SelectedCells[0].Item as Person;

        person.DisableEdit = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` into DataGrid binding instead of DataGridTextColumn